# React TypeScript display array images

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

*image does not render but show thumbnail*

[image: result]

- title works*

*what did i do wrong?*

image.ts

```
   export const images = [
   { id: '1', img: 'src/assets/shared/images/a.png', title: 'Images' },
   { id: '2', img: 'src/assets/shared/images/b.png', title: 'Images' },
   { id: '3', img: 'src/assets/shared/images/c.png', title: 'Images' },
   ];
```

display.tsx

```
   interface Images {
   id: string;
   img: string;
   title: string;
   }
   .....<>
  {images.map(({ id, img, title }: Images) => (
        <img src={String(img)} key={id} alt="img" />
      ))}
    </>
   .....
```

Comment: A direct path to your image won't work. Are you using webpack?

Comment: create react app with typescript, do i need to customize settings ?

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: thanks man, i did the same, but i wanted to it to be dynamic. and not hardcode all images,

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/ instead then. Also, not annoyed or anything, just trying to help, but you can find this information by googling "create react app images"

Comment: do you think its because of typescript config ? i have tried above on react only and it works.

Comment: Your images will not be bundled unless you import them or place them in the public folder like the two links describe.

Comment: have tried using public/images folder  too . no solutions yet